# How to fix 'Failed to add the foreign key' in SQL

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I'm creating a simple database in mySQL, and for how my model it's structured, i need to add the foreign keys using ALTER TABLE.

The error that i get is:

> Error Code: 1822. Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing
>   index for constraint 'esamereale_ibfk_4' in the referenced table
>   'laboratorio'

I know that this error usually comes when you try to point a value that is not unique or primary key, but i don't think that's the case.

This is my code.

```
CREATE SCHEMA ProgettoBD;

CREATE TABLE progettoBD.Paziente(
    CF_Paziente CHAR(16) PRIMARY KEY,
    Nome_Paziente VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
    Cognome_Paziente VARCHAR (15) NOT NULL,
    Indirizzo VARCHAR (30),
    Luogo VARCHAR (10),
    Data VARCHAR(10),
    Telefono VARCHAR(10),
    Mail VARCHAR(30),
    Cellulare VARCHAR(10)
    );

CREATE TABLE progettoBD.Esame(
    Codice_Esame CHAR(5) PRIMARY KEY,
    Nome_Esame VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL,
    Costo INT NOT NULL
    );

CREATE TABLE progettoBD.Prenotazione(
    Codice_Prenotazione CHAR(8) PRIMARY KEY,
    Paziente CHAR(16)
    );

CREATE TABLE progettoBD.EsameReale(
    Cod_Prenotazione CHAR (8),
    Tipo_Esame CHAR(5),
    Data VARCHAR(10),
    Ora VARCHAR(5),
    Urgenza VARCHAR(15),
    Parametri VARCHAR (30),
    Laboratorio CHAR (5),
    Ospedale CHAR(4),
    Medico CHAR (16),
    Diagnosi VARCHAR (50),
    PRIMARY KEY (Cod_Prenotazione, Tipo_Esame, Data, Ora)
    );

CREATE TABLE progettoBD.Laboratorio(
    Codice_Laboratorio CHAR(5),
    Ospedale CHAR(4),
    Nome_Laboratorio VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    Piano INT,
    Stanza INT,
    Responsabile_laboratorio CHAR(16),
    PRIMARY KEY (Codice_Laboratorio, Ospedale)

    );

CREATE TABLE progettoBD.Ospedale(
    Codice_Ospedale CHAR(4) PRIMARY KEY,
    Nome_Ospedale VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    Indirizzo VARCHAR(30),
    Responsabile_Ospedale CHAR(16)
    );

CREATE TABLE progettoBD.Reparto(
    Codice_Reparto CHAR(5),
    Ospedale CHAR(4),
    Nome_Reparto VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    Num_Telefono CHAR(10),
    PRIMARY KEY (Codice_Reparto, Ospedale)
    );

CREATE TABLE progettoBD.Medico(
    CF_Medico CHAR(16) PRIMARY KEY,
    Nome_Medico VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    Cognome VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    Indirizzo VARCHAR(30),
    Reparto CHAR(5),
    Ospedale CHAR(4)
    );

CREATE TABLE progettoBD.Primario(
    CF_Primario CHAR(16) PRIMARY KEY,
    Reparto_Primario CHAR(5),
    Ospedale CHAR(4)
    );

CREATE TABLE progettoBD.Volontario(
    CF_Volontario CHAR(16) PRIMARY KEY,
    Associazione VARCHAR(20)
    );

CREATE TABLE progettoBD.Specializzazione(
    Nome_Specializzazione VARCHAR(15) PRIMARY KEY
    );

CREATE TABLE progettoBD.Possiede(
    Primario VARCHAR(16),
    Specializzazione VARCHAR(15),
    PRIMARY KEY (Primario, Specializzazione)
    );

ALTER TABLE progettoBD.Prenotazione
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (Paziente) REFERENCES progettoBD.Paziente(CF_Paziente);

ALTER TABLE progettoBD.EsameReale
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (Cod_Prenotazione) REFERENCES progettoBD.Prenotazione(Codice_Prenotazione),
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (Tipo_Esame) REFERENCES progettoBD.Esame(Codice_Esame),
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (Laboratorio) REFERENCES progettoBD.Laboratorio(Codice_Laboratorio),
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (Ospedale) REFERENCES progettoBD.Laboratorio(Ospedale);

ALTER TABLE progettoBD.Laboratorio
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (Ospedale) REFERENCES progettoBD.Ospedale(Codice_Ospedale),
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (Responsabile_Laboratorio) REFERENCES progettoBD.Medico(CF_Medico);

ALTER TABLE progettoBD.Ospedale
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (Responsabile_Ospedale) REFERENCES progettoBD.Medico(CF_Medico);

ALTER TABLE progettoBD.Reparto
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (Ospedale) REFERENCES progettoBD.Ospedale(Codice_Ospedale);

ALTER TABLE progettoBD.Medico
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (Reparto) REFERENCES progettoBD.Reparto(Codice_Reparto),
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (Ospedale) REFERENCES progettoBD.Reparto(Ospedale);

ALTER TABLE progettoBD.Primario
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (CF_Primario) REFERENCES progettoBD.Medico(CF_Medico),
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (Reparto_Primario) REFERENCES progettoBD.Reparto(Codice_Reparto),
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (Ospedale) REFERENCES progettoBD.Reparto(Ospedale);

ALTER TABLE progettoBD.Volontario
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (CF_Volontario) REFERENCES progettoBD.Medico(CF_Medico);

ALTER TABLE progettoBD.Possiede
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (Primario) REFERENCES progettoBD.Primario(CF_Primario),
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (Specializzazione) REFERENCES progettoBD.Specializzazione(Nome_Specializzazione);
```

I already tried my code removing this line, and it works perfectly.

```
ADD FOREIGN KEY (Ospedale) REFERENCES progettoBD.Laboratorio(Ospedale);
```

Comment: This is an easily googleable faq. Also if you read the manual re FKs, which you should do before asking a question, it will tell you conditions that must be met. Also why is it that you "don't think that's the case" that you "point [to] a value [??] that is not unique or primary key" since you don't have "Ospedale" as a UNIQUE or PK, but only part of one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Ospedale` field in `progettoBD.Laboratorio` table is not the leftmost column of the index, hence the error message. You either need to index `Ospedale` separately, or you need to change the order of fields in `progettoBD.Laboratorio` table's primary key.

Answer (score 0):

Column Ospedale in table progettoBD.Laboratorio is not indexed. Furthermore progettoBD.Laboratorio.Ospedale refers to progettoBD.Ospedale.Codice_Ospedale. This is a very strange that you try to refer on field the second table that has a reference on the third table.

Comment: Ospelade field in Laboartorio table is indexed, just that index is not good enough for a foreign key.

Comment: it is included in composite index. It's not the same. It needs to create index only for only field.

Comment: I know what it means, I have already provided that answer :) I just remarked that the field in question is indexed.